# Проблемы с artisan в проекте laravel

Tags: laravel, artisan

Я учусь писать сайт по видео с ютубa. Установила openserver, laravel, подключила bootstrap. На начальных этапах использование artisan обойти смогла (в видео он часто используется), но на моменте с созданием файлов модели и миграции он нужен. Пыталась найти решение. Из попыток: скачан новый composer, composer install, composer update. Перепробовала также другие решения, но не получилось решить проблему.

При создании файла миграции и модели (php artisan make: model Contact -m) появляется ошибка:
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists(
should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be usedmporarily suppress the notice in C:\OSPanel\domains\tatktest\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349
Stack trace:
...

In Collection.php line 11:

During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should eit
be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to tempora
y suppress the notice in C:\OSPanel\domains\tatktest\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура папки. Запуск artisan производила после перехода в папку проекта.

Версии: PHP 8.2.11, laravel 7.29.

Подскажите как мне решить данную проблему?

Решения пыталась найти на данных страницах:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882897/laravel-artisan-not-working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994590/unable-to-execute-laravel-artisan-commands

Comment: Версию Laravel можете посмотреть в `composer.json`

Comment: консоль то вы используете от опенсервера?

Comment: К сожалению, не от него. Повторяла из видео, там автор использовал терминал редактора. Он через него запускал локальный сервер, который у меня не запускался из-за artisan, поэтому я решила использовать openserver, но дальнейшие действия повторяла за ним. Сам автор использует его на моменте создания и подключения БД. Но использование консоли openserver решило мою проблему. Спасибо Вам).